# Pagination PHP script works on wamp but not on live server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pagination

I used a code for pagination of the search result. It works fine on the wamp but when i run it on the live server, only page one shows the result and nothing comes up for page two. I think something is wrong with the get functions that I am using. Anybody can guess the error or suggest me a solution. Following is the code used.

```
$query2 = "SELECT student_information.searcher, student_information.student_number, student_information.birth_date, student_information.first_name, student_information.last_name, student_information.second_name, student_information.gender, student_information.reg_date, student_information.email_add1, student_information.email_add2, student_information.home_phone, student_information.business_phone, student_information.home_address, student_information.city, student_information.province, student_information.postal_code, student_information.country, student_information.native_language, student_information.canadian_citizen, student_information.date_entry, student_information.ref_name, student_information.ref_email, student_information.wdhau, student_information.status, student_information.school_name, student_information.school_number, student_information.school_add, student_information.special_exam_req, student_information.guidance_coun, student_information.phone_school, student_information.fax_school, student_information.email_school, student_information.last_year_att, student_information.min, student_information.oen, student_information.sh_osr, student_information.sp_need, student_information.iep_rec, student_information.academic_fr_rp, student_information.med_note_rec, student_information.osr, student_information.req_date, student_information.date_osr_tran, student_information.date_osr_received, student_information.mse_plar, student_information.mse_plar_date, student_information.literacy_status, student_information.com_inv_hours, student_information.oces_dip FROM student_information,course_information Where student_information.searcher = 'y' ORDER by student_information.first_name ";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
        confirm_query($result2);    
            $num_rows5 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
            $page_rows = 2;
            $total_pages = ceil($num_rows5/$page_rows);
            if($total_pages<1){
                $total_pages = 1;
            }
            $pagenum = 1;
            if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
                $pagenum = $_GET['pn'];
            }
            if($pagenum<1){
                $pagenum = 1;
            }else if($pagenum > $total_pages){
                $pagenum = $total_pages;
            }
        $limit = 'LIMIT '.($pagenum-1)*$page_rows.','.$page_rows;

$query = "SELECT student_information.searcher, student_information.student_number, student_information.birth_date, student_information.first_name, student_information.last_name, student_information.second_name, student_information.gender, student_information.reg_date, student_information.email_add1, student_information.email_add2, student_information.home_phone, student_information.business_phone, student_information.home_address, student_information.city, student_information.province, student_information.postal_code, student_information.country, student_information.native_language, student_information.canadian_citizen, student_information.date_entry, student_information.ref_name, student_information.ref_email, student_information.wdhau, student_information.status, student_information.school_name, student_information.school_number, student_information.school_add, student_information.special_exam_req, student_information.guidance_coun, student_information.phone_school, student_information.fax_school, student_information.email_school, student_information.last_year_att, student_information.min, student_information.oen, student_information.sh_osr, student_information.sp_need, student_information.iep_rec, student_information.academic_fr_rp, student_information.med_note_rec, student_information.osr, student_information.req_date, student_information.date_osr_tran, student_information.date_osr_received, student_information.mse_plar, student_information.mse_plar_date, student_information.literacy_status, student_information.com_inv_hours, student_information.oces_dip FROM student_information,course_information Where student_information.searcher = 'y' ORDER by student_information.first_name $limit";


    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirm_query($result); 

            $text1 = "Showing <b>2</b> of total <b> $num_rows5</b> results found.";
            $text2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$total_pages</b>";

            $paginationctrl = '';
            if($total_pages!=1){
                  if($pagenum>1){
                    $previous = $pagenum-1;
                    $paginationctrl .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp ';
                    for($i=$pagenum-4; $i<$pagenum;$i++){
                      if($i>0){
                          $paginationctrl .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp ';
                      }

                     }
                  }
                  $paginationctrl .= ''.$pagenum.'&nbsp ';
                  for($i=$pagenum+1; $i<=$total_pages;$i++){
                      $paginationctrl .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp ';
                      if($i>=$pagenum+4){
                          break;
                      }
                  }
                  if($pagenum!=$total_pages){
                      $next=$pagenum+1;
                      $paginationctrl .= '&nbsp &nbsp <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a>';
                  }
              }
            if (!$result) {

      // Failure
      $_SESSION["message"] = "Admin creation failed. " .mysqli_error($connection);
    }
 }`
```

Comment: Does your database on the live server match the database on your development environment? The other possible explanations are that you have php modules enabled on your wamp server but not your live location, or that you have a different version of php on your live server, or it could even be that your apache directives are different on your live server. Do you know what lines in your code are being hit currently?

Comment: You showed us the code for the data access. How do you know the issue in not on your web page?

Comment: Since it works on one server and not on the other, the problem likely stems from configurations on the second server. Make sure that the configurations are alright.

Comment: I tested everything. other than the $_get all other code works perfectly fine. All the site is matched with the development environment. its not on the webpage because only thing that is echoed on the webpage is the result of the limit and text which are generated says page ___ of total pages. the blank comes from the get variable pn but its shows 1, which is when the get is not there. So that is the reason I showed the code with the error. The total database entries and all post things work file just the get is giving the error/